# Jquery/Javascript Calculation: not getting desired answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm to AutoCalculate Materials for Consumption...
let say i have 4 materials

```
1) mopp 34u-234mm // Here 34 is micron  
2) bopp 43u-234mm // here 43 is micron  
3) mcpp 85u-234mm // here 85 is micron  
4) patt 12u-234mm // here 12 is micron
```

and the order is `1000 kg`

now i am to calculate materials for one ton. how much material to consume in one ton.

the formula is to calculate material

```
micron X density = ratio1    
micron X density = ratio2    
micron X density = ratio3    
micron X density = ratio4
totalRation = ratio1 + ratio2 + ratio3 + ratio4
```

material1 is to consume = `ratio1 / totalRatio x Order Quantity // (in this case 1000 kg)`

i am calculated closed to my calculation. but the first field calculate fine and other 3 is become 0 0 0..

Here is [**My Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2c792hj/) Please Check what i am mistaking.. please corrention me. thanks..

and suggest me the best way to calculate this. is my approach is fine or i should use something different

Comment: pls check javascript thorougly....


$.each( $('.materials') , function(i){
      var $this = $( this ),
       $density = $this.data('density').toFixed(2),
       $value = $this.val(),
       $micron = $value.toLowerCase().match(/([1-9])?[1-9][1-9](?=u)/ig);
      if ($value) {
       perHead.push( $density*$micron );
      };
     });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k2c792hj/4/) the fix

The issue is with the density variable. Only the first one has a value different from 0.

```
 $density = $this.data('density').toFixed(2)
```

replace with

```
$density = Number($this.attr("data-density")).toFixed(2),
```

Comment: but please explain why $this.data('density') don't work for more than 1 field?

Comment: you have to setup the value for the element      $this.data("density",ui.item.density) instead of         $this.attr( 'data-density', ui.item.density );